# How to read a text file into parallel arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I must have a function that reads card information from a text file
(cards.txt) and insert them to parallel arrays in the main program using a pointer.

I have successfully read the text file, but cannot successfully insert the info to the arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void readCards();

int main() {
  ifstream inputFile;
  const int SIZE = 10;
  int id[SIZE];
  string beybladeName[SIZE];
  string productCode[SIZE];
  string type[SIZE];
  string plusMode[SIZE];
  string system[SIZE];

  readCards();

  return 0;
}

void readCards() {
  ifstream inputFile;
  const int SIZE = 10;
  int id[SIZE];
  string beybladeName[SIZE];
  string productCode[SIZE];
  string type[SIZE];
  string plusMode[SIZE];
  string system[SIZE];
  int i = 0;

  inputFile.open("cards.txt");
  cout << "Reading all cards information..." << endl;
  if (inputFile) {
    while (inputFile >> id[i] >> beybladeName[i] >> productCode[i] >> type[i] >> plusMode[I] >>
      system[I]) {
      i++;
    }
    cout << "All cards information read." << endl;
  }
  inputFile.close();

  for (int index = 0; index < SIZE; index++) {
    cout << "#:" << id[index] << endl;
    cout << "Beyblade Name: " << beybladeName[index] << endl;
    cout << "Product Code: " << productCode[index] << endl;
    cout << "Type: " << type[index] << endl;
    cout << "Plus Mode: " << plusMode[index] << endl;
    cout << "System: " << system[index] << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried for "*insert them to parallel arrays in the MAIN PROGRAM using a POINTER*"?

Comment: Learn about it here: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-pointers/

Comment: On a side note, anytime you want to use multiple parallel arrays, you probably should have a single array instead whose element type is a struct/class to hold all of the info for each index in the array.

Comment: @Wind 1) It's too big a topic, and 2) How come you've been given a assignment involving pointers without being taught anything about pointers?

Comment: @john 
I had being taught about pointers, but I have no idea where to start, that's the nothing knowledge mean, because I being taught by pointers a single value or multiple value, when until arrays, I am blur...
Sorry if bringing any inconvenience, thanks for answering me!! Appreciate your help!

Comment: @john I have done all my assignments, thank you for this few days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you have two sets of arrays, one in `main`, and one in `readCards`. You need one set of arrays in `main` and to pass those arrays (using pointers) to `readCards`. Like this

```
void readCards(int* id, string* beybladeName, string* productCode, string* type, string* plusMode, string* system);

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    const int SIZE = 10;
    int id[SIZE]; 
    string beybladeName[SIZE];
    string productCode[SIZE];
    string type[SIZE];
    string plusMode [SIZE];
    string system [SIZE];

    readCards(id, beybladeName, productCode, type, plusMode, system);

    return 0;
} 

void readCards(int* id, string* beybladeName, string* productCode, string* type, string* plusMode, string* system)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: How about the pointers part?

Comment: `readCards` has six pointer parameters.

Comment: And `readCards` probably should have a `size` parameter so it knows when to stop.

Comment: @jkb Ideally, yes, but looking at the rest of the code it seems that the number of cards is hard coded as 10.

Comment: @Wind In case it is not clear your `readCards` function does not need to change, apart from the change I have made above, and deleting the array declarations you currently have in `readCards`.